# Escaping a directory in a $PATH-like list

Tags: unix, path, environment-variables, escaping

I'm developing a wrapper for LibGit2, the Git library.
And I come out with a problem:

Many GIT functions accept **path lists**, that is, a string
composed of a series of paths separated by a token,
that LibGit2 makes available to me. In my Linux, it is a colon (`:`).

The issue appears when I ask me:
**what if the path contains this token?**

Can it be escaped someway? `\:` or so?
Will it be supported out-of-the-box in Windows?

I know it's not common to have a directory containing `:` in his
name, but as a wrapper I have to be prepared for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't checked *libgit2*, but neither *git* nor various `$PATH` users – such as the Glibc `execvpe()` function and  various shells (*dash*, *bash*) – support any form of escaping – if a directory name contains a `:`, it simply cannot be used as part of path-related environment variables.

On Windows, the path separator is `;` – you should be able to use `PATH_SEP` or a similar constant to find the value – and again, escaping is not supported anywhere.

If the user gives you a path like `/usr/foo:bar`, then they might be *expecting* it to be split into two directories, so just do that.